# Using stacks to reverse string?

Tags: java, string, stack, reverse

This is my code so far, I need to create a reverse string so input= "hello" will output = "olleh"... The errors I'm having is in push and pop part of the code. I can't use StringBuffer. The error is -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:  l cannot be resolved l cannot be resolved
>
> at E.reverse(E.java:10) at E.main(E.java:17)

Can you please help?

```
public class Rev {

    public static String reverse(String s) {

        MyStack st = new MyStack();
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            String k = st.toString();
            st.push(s);
        }
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            String p = st.pop();
            return s;
        }}
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(reverse("hello"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is:

```
 private Stack s = new Stack();

    public void reversestack( String str )
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
        {
            s.push( str.charAt( j ) );
        }

        while(s.isEmpty() != true)
        {    
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like this:-

```
public class StringReverse {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "";
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter a string to be reversed: ");

        str = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

            stack.push(str.substring(i,i+1));
        }

        String strrev = "";
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){

            strrev += stack.pop(); 
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse of the string \"" + str + "\" is: \"" + strrev + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use String reverse(String s)

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/data_reverse.htm Does this help??